# How to replace first occurrence of whitespace with comma?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have string as :

```
string sku= "plmca60     5";
```

I just wanted to replace first blank space with comma. Hence I tried:

```
sku.replace(" ",",");
```

But it  given me:

```
sku="plmca60,,,,,5";
```

Its because five blank spaces are there in the string. But I want to replace just first occurrence of blank space like;

```
sku="plmca60,    5"
```

How can I do like this?

Comment: Just space, or *all* whitespace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [`String.Replace` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup> returns your string as `plmca60,,,,,5` because from documentation;

> Returns a new string in which **all occurrences** of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

You don't need regex for that.

You can use [`String.IndexOf(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get first index of a white space and a little bit [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.remove%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods combination.

> Reports the zero-based index of the **first** occurrence of the specified
>   string in this instance

```
string sku = "plmca60     5";
int index = sku.IndexOf(" ");
sku = sku.Remove(index, 1).Insert(index, ",");
Console.WriteLine(sku);
```

Result will be;

```
plmca60,    5
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/ajo3De)</kbd>.

1: <sup>Remember, it is `Replace`, not `replace`. C# is case sensitive language.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You could use capturing groups like below,

```
@"^(\S*)\s"
```

OR

```
@"^(\S*) "
```

Replace the matched space by,

```
$1,
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sS3jS5/9)

`\S` matches a non-whitespace character. `\S*` matches zero or more non-whitespace characters. `^` asserts that we are at the start.

**Code:**

```
string sku= "plmca60 5";
string result = Regex.Replace(sku, @"^(\S*) ", "$1,");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadLine();
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/EVs7sp)

Answer (score 2):

By using   `Regex.Replace`

```
var regex = new Regex(Regex.Escape(" "));
var newText = regex.Replace("plmca60     5", ",", 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an optimized solution but it works,

```
string sku = "plmca60     5";
string[] skyArr = sku.Split(' ');
skyArr[1] = ",";
string resultString = "";
foreach (string str in skyArr) 
{
     if (str == "")
         resultString += " ";
     else
         resultString += str;
     }
}
Console.WriteLine(resultString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all whitespace with ", ". For example:

`sku = Regex.Replace(sku, @"\s+", ", ");`

Answer (score 1):

```
            string sku = "plmca60     5";
            int pos = sku.IndexOf(" ");
            char[] a = sku.ToCharArray();
            a[pos]=a[pos].ToString().Replace(" ", ",").ToCharArray()[0];
            var result = new string(a);
```

This is dirty way. Meanwhile trying to find out shorter way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would capture 1 space with 0 or more spaces after that in a capture group. That way you can replace it with a comma and the content of the capture-group (which was any spaces after the first one)

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\s(\s*)", ",$1");
```

**[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP4bK6/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Two line version:

```
string sku = "plmca60     5";
Console.WriteLine(sku.Insert(sku.IndexOf(" ")).Remove(sku.Index(" "));
```

Comment: this doesn't even compile (missing ')', `String.Insert` requires 2 parameters).